# Mask SVG with an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have been tinkering around with the code posted below for a while now and I can not seem to do what I need to do with support for Chrome and Firefox. My aim is to have an image fill (cover) the whole area of the SVG.

```css
.trap-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.trap-container svg {
  position: absolute;
}
.trap-content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="trap-container">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,70 0,100">
    </polygon>
  </svg>
  <div class="trap-content">Legal
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For arguments sake this image: https://i.imgur.com/WHnTGPB.jpg?1

Comment: Where would this be placed? As the `background-image` of the body? You can modify your code above to include the image with the URL that you have provided.

Comment: It would be masked to the shape like this - http://i.imgur.com/Gp1vNHF.png

Comment: edited so now Legal is below the image

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wejuwevusi

Comment: sorry i edited your question instead of my answer -oops!!!!!!!

Comment: do you get the issue with the jsbin link  http://jsbin.com/jolitocewe  I put in extra margin and padding important in other classes

Comment: The issue is the image you have used. Use a different image as the svg is not applied

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/#toc-masking

Answer (score 0):

You can clip an image with a path, by first creating a path and then adding an `<image>` element with the `clip-path` attribute assigned to the path.

```css
.trap-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.trap-container svg {
  position: absolute;
}
.trap-content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 10%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="trap-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
       class="svg-graphic" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <g>
      <clipPath id="banner-mask">
        <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,70 0,100" />
      </clipPath>
    </g>
    <a xlink:href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
      <image clip-path="url(#banner-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/WHnTGPB.jpg?1" />
    </a>
  </svg>
  <div class="trap-content">Legal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try this method before and as you can see the image is stretched.